# How to extract lines in specific order

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a document:

```
column1: 23
column2: 42
kolumn3: 24
column1: 24
column2: 35
kolumn3: 46
column1: 25
column2: 42
column1: 35
column2: 45
kolumn3: 52
```

And I'd like my output to be:

```
column1: 23
column2: 42
kolumn3: 24
column1: 24
column2: 35
kolumn3: 46
column1: 35
column2: 45
kolumn3: 52
```

The output must be in `column1`, `column2`, `kolumn3` order. Remove everything that is not in this order.

Is it possible to do this in `grep`, `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='column1: [0-9]+\ncolumn2: [0-9]+\nkolumn3: [0-9]+\n' '{printf RT}' file
```

The record separator `RS` is a regex set to catch the 3 consecutive lines.

The only statement is to print the record terminator `RT` leaving out everything that is not caught by `RS`.

Comment: Pretty n33t. Will match if there is something like `ANYTHINGcolumn1:` but fixable, I assume.

Comment: @JamesBrown No it won't. It only prints the record separator, nothing else. If there is garbage data before the record separator (like you mention) it won't print it. If there is garbage data with the wanted lines, it would simply not match and no also not print it.

Comment: What I meant is that if  the `file` is: `ANYTHINGcolumn1: 23\ncolumn2: 42\nkolumn3: 24` it will get outputed excluding the `ANYTHING`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Okay... That's exactly what I understood from OP's question...

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick in awk, let's call it testcol.awk:

```
$1=="column1:" {l1=$0; n=2;}
$1=="column2:" && n==2 {l2=$0; n=3;}
$1=="kolumn3:" && n==3 {print l1 "\n" l2 "\n" $0; n=1}
```

Then run something like

```
awk -f testcol.awk your_input_file
```

Comment: Nice state machine. My only recommendation is to not use shell redirection here. It's not needed. Just use the input file as the last argument on the command-line.

Comment: @Rafael what do you mean, please? I'm noob at awk.

Comment: I was just pointing out that shell redirection is not needed. `awk -f test.awk file` is sufficient.

Comment: n needs to be reset, otherwise you could have several "kolumn3"s in a row, and it'll print each one, no?

Answer (score 0):

Another (a brain bug that wouldn't leave me alone before I typed it in, pretty untested though):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    p="column1:column2:kolumn3:"  # comparison pat- NO, something else ;D
}
p~"^" b $1 {                      # if gathered $1 buffer matches the p
    b=b $1                        # keep collecting
    c=c $0 ORS
    if(p==b) {                    # prefect match deserves to be outputed
        printf c
        b=c=""                    # reset buffer vars
    }
    next                          
}
{                                 # a non-match means a reset and restart 
    b=$1                          # for buffer vars
    c=$0 ORS
}' file
```

Output:

```
column1: 23
column2: 42
kolumn3: 24
column1: 24
column2: 35
kolumn3: 46
column1: 35
column2: 45
kolumn3: 52
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/^column1:.*\ncolumn2:/!D;N;/\nkolumn3:/b;s/.*\n//;ta' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if they do not match `column1:` followed by `column2:` delete the first and repeat. Otherwise, append a third line and if this matches `kolumn3:` print all three lines, if not, remove the first two lines and jump back to the beginning of the sed script.

Another solution:

```
sed -n '/\n/!N;N;/^column1:[^\n]*\ncolumn2:[^\n]*\nkolumn3:[^\n]*$/p;//!D' file
```